# Store stmt results in an array, inside of an array

Tags: php, mysqli

So I am trying to create multiple "result" arrays and fill them with the results of my statement, inside a "main" array.

However it seems to be that the result arrays are getting overwritten each time the loop passes instead of creating an additional array.

My code:

```
function retrieve_clients() {
    $coach_id = $_SESSION['user_details']['id'];

    $connection = connection();
    $statement = select($connection, '*', 'relations', 'coach_id', '=');
    $statement->bind_param('i', $coach_id);

    if ($statement->execute()) {
        $statement->bind_result($id, $coach_id, $client_id, $relation_date);

        while ($statement->fetch()) {
            $_SESSION['clients'] = array(
                array($id, $coach_id, $client_id, $relation_date)
            );
       }
    }
$statement->close();
}
```

I can't figure it out anymore. Please spare me because I'm still new to programming.

Comment: What is the database library you used fof "select()"

Comment: [Here's a link to the PHP manual that describes how to add items to arrays.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add another dimension to your clients, by adding `[]` to the end of the variable.

```
$_SESSION['clients'][] = array(
            array($id, $coach_id, $client_id, $relation_date)
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answers are on the right track, however they add an unnecessary and probably undesirable dimension.  Try adding a dynamic dimension with `[]` but remove one of the `array` dimensions that overwrites:

```
$_SESSION['clients'][] = array($id, $coach_id, $client_id, $relation_date);
```

Comment: Whoops, I missed that. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're replacing the value of clients in following line,

```
$_SESSION['clients'] = array(
                array($id, $coach_id, $client_id, $relation_date)
            );
```

What you need to do is create an array of clients first before loop and then append each array in the main array.

Like this,

```
$_SESSION['clients']=array();
while ($statement->fetch()) {
            $_SESSION['clients'][] = array(
                array($id, $coach_id, $client_id, $relation_date)
            );
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` itself an array. No need to declare it.

Comment: +1 for initializing `$_SESSION['clients']`. I think it's a good idea, even if it's not absolutely necessary. That way if the query doesn't return anything `$_SESSION['clients']` will be an empty array instead of an undefined index.

Comment: Yeah that's why I've initialized it as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor, stop using mysqli (as well as that home-brewed "select" function).

With PDO you'll have a code that is sane:

```
function retrieve_clients() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM relation WHERE coach_id = ?";
    $statement = connection()->prepare($sql); // here goes your SQL
    $statement->execute([$_SESSION['user_details']['id']]); // here goes a parameter
    $_SESSION['clients'] = $statement->fetchAll(); // and here you have your array
}
```

Comment: Prepared statements are so much easier with PDO.